# Is the problem Find all $x,y \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $\binom{x}{2} = \binom{y}{5}$ solved?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, combinatorial-number-theory

I was recently browsing and came upon this document which gives some open problems involving Diophantine Equations.
Document: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/07-workshop-problems.pdf

Upon searching a bit, I found that the first problem given has been solved. Is the second problem also solved? 
The problem is Find all $x,y \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $\binom{x}{2} = \binom{y}{5}$.

Comment: It looks a bit misleading.  The problem is to find all $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\binom{x}{2} = \binom{y}{5}$.  It sounds like you are claiming that they are equal for all $x, y$, which they're not of course.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/Permutations.faq.question.1019557.amp

Comment: @Randall thanks for that - have edited the question accordingly....@lab bhattacharjee I fail to see what that link has to do with my question or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: de Weger, Equal binomial coefficients: some elementary considerations, J. Number Thy. 63 (1997) 373-386, gives the nontrivial examples 78-choose-2 equals 15-choose-5 equals 3003, and 153-choose-2 equals 19-choose-5 equals 11628, and conjectures there are no others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Blokhuis, Brouwer, and de Weger, Binomial collisions and near collisions, [Integers 17 (2017)](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol17.html) #A64, the question was settled in Bugeaud, Mignotte, Siksek, Stoll, and Tengely, [Integral points on hyperelliptic curves](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ant/1513797332), Algebra Number Theory 2 (2008) 859-885; there are no nontrivial solutions, other than those given in the comment.